# Python:Fill between three curves

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, google-colaboratory

I have this figure with three curves that i would like to fill between them:

[image]

I'm using this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a=np.arange(-5,300,2)

def f(a): return a**2

def slope(a):
  slope=2*(a)
  return slope

xp = 60
yp = f(xp)
def line(a, xp, yp):
    return slope(xp)*(a - xp) + yp
plt.plot(a, f(a))
plt.scatter(xp, yp, color='C1', s=50)
plt.plot(a, line(a, xp, yp), 'C1--', linewidth = 2)
    
xp1=250
yp1=f(xp1)

plt.scatter(xp1, yp1, color='C1', s=50)
plt.plot(a, line(a, xp1, yp1), 'C3--', linewidth = 2)

plt.fill_between(a,f(a),line(a, xp1, yp1),line(a, xp, yp),color='green')

plt.show()
```

The output is:

[image]

I want to have a filling limits which is `yp1` and `yp`.
I tried to use `where` argument in the `fillbetween` command like below :

```
plt.fill_between(a,f(a),line(a, xp1, yp1),line(a, xp, yp),where=[(a>yp)and (a<yp1) for a in a],color='green')
```

but for some reason im getting this error: `TypeError: fill_between() got multiple values for argument 'where'`

Any help or ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error `TypeError: fill_between() got multiple values for argument 'where'` comes from the fact that you provided `where` twice, since the signature of [fill_between](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.fill_between.html) is `Axes.fill_between(self, x, y1, y2=0, where=None, ...)`. In your code, `line(a, xp, yp)` is provided as `where`.

What you actually want to do is choose carefully your `y1` and `y2` limits, in addition to using `where=(a > yp) & (a < yp1)` to restrict the filled area between the two dots.

[image]

I have changed the variables names a bit to something I find more readable. Arrays start with a capital letter and single values are lowercase.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(X):
    return X**2

def slope(x):
  return 2*x

def line(X, xp, yp):
    return slope(xp)*(X - xp) + yp

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
X = np.arange(-5, 300, 2)

Y0 = f(X)
ax.plot(X, Y0)

x_left = 60
y_left = f(x_left)
Y1 = line(X, x_left, y_left)
ax.scatter(x_left, y_left, color='C1', s=50)
ax.plot(X, Y1, 'C1--', linewidth = 2)

x_right = 250
y_right = f(x_right)
Y2 = line(X, x_right, y_right)
ax.scatter(x_right, y_right, color='C1', s=50)
ax.plot(X, Y2, 'C3--', linewidth = 2)

where = (x_left < X) & (X < x_right)
Ylower = [max(y1, y2) for (y1, y2) in zip(Y1, Y2)]
ax.fill_between(X, Ylower, Y0, where=where, color='green')

fig.show()
```